# How to make garden in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

How to make a garden such as following in LaTeX, using Ti*k*Z? It's interesting to know conceptual approaches, e.g. using nodes with image or other tikz elements.

[image]

Comment: Sure, it is possible. It would also be rather difficult, this kind of graphics is usually much easier to make with a drawing program.

Comment: Do you want to match this image closely, or do you want a showcase of tikz gardens (in which case adding the “fun” tag may help)?

Comment: No I dont want to match 100%. Just a rectangular garden with some flowers and plants.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for ChatGPT or other AI code generators.

Comment: @HenriMenke see my answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Easy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{garden.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure: zero order approximation ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments, Henri Menke suggested asking ChatGPT. Since the question is tagged "fun" I thought I would give that a go.

The initial prompt was "write tikz code generating a picture of a rectangular garden with some flowers and plants". Its first answer generated an error, but after I pasted the error back into ChatGPT it fixed it and gave me this (code below):

[image]

I thought that wasn't bad for a first attempt, so I asked it to add some extra details to the plants and flowers, such as stems and leaves. Unfortunately, the result was this:

[image]

I tried clicking "regenerate response" several times, but the results were always similarly weird, and I conclude that ChatGPT doesn't have enough of an idea of what plants and flowers look like to be able to draw them properly. This is maybe not surprising given that it's only ever been trained on text and not images. I bet GPT 4 or 5 would do a better job though, if someone has access.

Here's the code it gave me. This is 100% written by ChatGPT, I didn't edit it at all.

first image:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  % Garden dimensions
  \def\gardenwidth{10}
  \def\gardenheight{8}

  % Draw the garden
  \draw[green!60!black, fill=green!20] (0,0) rectangle (\gardenwidth,\gardenheight);

  % Add some flowers
  \foreach \x/\y/\color in {{2/2/red},{4/6/blue},{8/4/yellow},{6/2/purple}}
    \draw[\color, fill=\color] (\x,\y) circle (0.3);

  % Add some plants
  \foreach \x/\y in {{1/6},{3/3},{7/7},{9/2}}
    \draw[brown!70!black, fill=green!60!black] (\x,\y) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

second image:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  % Garden dimensions
  \def\gardenwidth{10}
  \def\gardenheight{8}

  % Draw the garden
  \draw[green!60!black, fill=green!20] (0,0) rectangle (\gardenwidth,\gardenheight);

  % Add some flowers
  \foreach \x/\y/\color in {{2/2/red},{4/6/blue},{8/4/yellow},{6/2/purple}}
    {
      \draw[brown!70!black, fill=brown!70!black] (\x,\y+0.3) circle (0.1);
      \draw[\color, fill=\color] (\x,\y) circle (0.3);
      \draw[\color, fill=\color] (\x-0.2,\y+0.2) circle (0.1);
      \draw[\color, fill=\color] (\x+0.2,\y+0.2) circle (0.1);
      \draw[\color, thick] (\x,\y+0.3) -- (\x,\y+0.7);
    }

  % Add some plants
  \foreach \x/\y in {{1/6},{3/3},{7/7},{9/2}}
    {
      \draw[brown!70!black, fill=green!60!black] (\x,\y) circle (0.5);
      \draw[green!60!black, thick] (\x,\y+0.5) -- (\x,\y+1.5);
      \draw[green!60!black, thick] (\x-0.3,\y+0.8) -- (\x,\y+1.5) -- (\x+0.3,\y+0.8);
      \draw[green!60!black, thick] (\x-0.2,\y+0.7) -- (\x,\y+1.5) -- (\x+0.2,\y+0.7);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it. Basic idea, demonstrated below:

- prepare images with transparent backgrounds
- place them via nodes, i.e. with graphics as content instead of text
- alternatively you can use tikz' picture and draw sunflowers etc. once by tikz

Details:

- you'll need `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`
- background is set via `background rectangle`
- other meadow areas can be drawn as a `closed path` with `rounded corners`
- place sunflowers, flowers, tulips, gras, bushes etc. as needed *(note variations of scale)*
- you can use anchors of some nodes for more precise positioning *(see gras and bushes)*
- add more images as needed *(the ones I used are at the end)*

Remarks:

- tikz provides more sopistication, like using loops for the placement of bushes
- or random things like you might need for the rocks in front
- etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tikz[background rectangle/.style={fill=orange!45},show background rectangle]{

    % ~~~ orange meadows ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \definecolor{lo}{rgb}{.95,.83,.78}
    \draw [lo, fill=lo, rounded corners=20pt] (-7,-3) -- (-2,2) -- (0,1.3) -- (1.5,-1) -- (0,-1.5) -- (3,-2) -- (0,-3) -- cycle;

    % ~~~ sunflowers ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (S1) at (6,4) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{sunflower}};
    \node at (4.5,3.5)  {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{sunflower}};
    \node (S3) at (5,3) {\includegraphics[scale=.7]{sunflower}};
    
    % ~~~ flowers ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (3,-4)     {\includegraphics[scale=1]{flower}};
    \node at (4.5,-2)   {\includegraphics[scale=.6]{flower}};
    \node at (6,-4.5)   {\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{flower}};
    
    % ~~~ tulips ~~~~~~~    
    \node at (-5,3.5)   {\includegraphics[scale=1]{tulip}};
    \node at (-4,4.5)   {\includegraphics[scale=.9]{tulip}};
    
    % ~~~ gras ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (S3.south) {\includegraphics[scale=.7]{gras1}};
    \node at (S1.south) {\includegraphics[scale=.7]{gras2}};
    \node at (0,0)      {\includegraphics[scale=1]{gras1}};
    \node at (2,2)      {\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{gras2}};
    
    % ~~~ bushes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (B1) at (-8,4)        {\includegraphics[scale=1]{bush}};
    \node (B2) at (B1.south) [yshift=-4mm]  {\includegraphics[scale=1]{bush}};
    \node (B3) at (B2.south) [yshift=-4mm]  {\includegraphics[scale=1]{bush}};
}

\end{document}
```

[image: bushes][image: flower]
[image: gras1][image: gras2]
[image: sunflower][image: tulip]